# Distributing/Installing Visual Studio Package Manager Settings to a team

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, nuget

We are in the process of moving several projects to internally hosted NuGet packages.  As part of this, some Visual Studio settings will need to be changed across our entire development team, namely all of the Package Manager tree node and Debugging -> Symbols, under Tools -> Options.

I've done a fair bit of searching and have not been able to find much yet.  Exporting VS settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings) does not seem to control these settings.  The only thing I have been able to find so far is a deployment script [here](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/348055).

Does anybody have any idea how to easily and cleanly disseminate these settings across a team?  Thanks!

Comment: Yep.  I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and figured out most of it, but we wound up doing it manually anyway.  You can use the nuget sources command
from [command line reference](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference)

Then there's a global config file:  C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
So you can just use a powershell script or installer or anything to deploy that file out.

Then the rest are [hierachical](http://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.1).